# How can I open a mobile app (eg Facebook) via a browser redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, android, facebook, redirect

I've been searching for the past few hours for this and decided I'd just try asking.

I have a URL that people will visit, it loads a PHP page which checks a database for a specific Facebook link, and then instantly redirects them. I want it to open the app if they have it, otherwise it will go to the browser version.

The issue I'm facing is that I can't get the Facebook app to open when it's a redirect. If I instead create a button or a link and I tap on it, it will launch the app correctly, but navigating to that same link without the user interaction will not work.

I know it's possible because I've seen it done elsewhere, but I guess there is something I'm missing.

I've tried using headers("Location: fb://profile/username") and have also tried other Javascript options such as window.open, window.location, window.location.href and window.location.replace

So far I've only tested this an on android phone. The link initially launches in the chrome app.

If you have a look at this Youtube video, you'll see it's doing what I want to do. It goes to a website and then straight away launches the app.

https://youtu.be/Acl7JnRFxzI?t=17

Thanks!

Comment: _“If I instead create a button or a link and I tap on it, it will launch the app correctly”_ - then I’d try if that also works, if you don’t manually tap on it, but trigger a click event on it via JavaScript. If it does, then that could be your solution - send the user to a page where this automatic click will be triggered.

Comment: @cbroe I did also try this last night after making this post but it fails to work. If the link instead goes to Google or any other website, it will work, but if I'm trying to open the app, it won't unless clicked manually :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you talked about Deep linking.

Deep linking is not supported on Web so there aren’t the same functionalities as on Android and iOS. You still need to guide your users in the right direction, so we recommend adding a link to your login page.

Comment: Though the video uses iPhones, I have contacted that business and they said that it works the same on androids also. Their website has a list of compatible phones and it basically lists all androids, so it should be possible somehow.